# X, Y and Z are independent random variables with the same Uniform [0,1] distribution.

Tags: probability

Find $E[(XY-Z)^2]$.

I simplified $(XY-Z)^2$ into $X^2Y^2-2XYZ+Z^2$. So now it's $E(X^2)E(Y^2)-2E(X)E(Y)E(Z)+E(Z^2)$. I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: You've written $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, and $E(Y)$ as three different things, but they're all equal. Same goes for the second moments (the expected values of the squares). So you just have two numbers to calculate (say, $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$).

Comment: @MrFranzén the point of OP expanding the power in the way that they did is so that they can take the expectation of each term separately, then separate independent factors in each term.

Comment: @SophieMacDonald Right, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[Z] = \frac{1}{2} $

and

$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \frac{1}{3} $.

Comment: so it would be 7/36?